# Android Bluetooth- MAC address

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I am trying to get the MAC address of a bluetooth device when I click on a device in the listview. I want to pass in the MAC address in

`BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);`

Is there a way I can extract the MAC address when I choose a device on the listview. Thanks

```
 @Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    if (mBluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
        mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
    }
    if (listAdapter.getItem(i).contains("Paired")) {

        BluetoothDevice selectedDevice = devices.get(i);
        BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
        mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        try {
            btSocket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
            btSocket.connect();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            try {
                btSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e2) {
            }
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Android, after starting a bluetooth device scan, we get the address of remote bluetooth devices, as a broadcast message on a `BroadcastReceiver` we have registered. Below code sample does that.

```
//receive remote device details including address
BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Sring action = intent.getAction();

        // When discovery finds a device
        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
            // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
            BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            String deviceAddress =  device.getAddress());
        }
    }
}

//register receiver 
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter); 

//start bluetooth scan 
BluetoothAdapter mBtAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
mBtAdapter.startDiscovery();
```

To answer your *specific* case, I assume you are using the `BluetoothChat`([1](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BluetoothChat)) Android sample code to create a ListView from paired devices after the scan. If that is the case, you can get the device address as in the Android code sample([2](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BluetoothChat/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/bluetoothchat/DeviceListActivity.java#L174))

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    String info = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();
    String address = info.substring(info.length() - 17);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
BluetoothDevice
```

has method to get the mac address `getAddress` [REF](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#getAddress())